# AWS SQS Why is requests number so high

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a simple lambda app that is not in production right now, only being used for testing and debugging. The function sends a message to SQS to perform CRUD operations on an external application. I've set this function to be invoked by SQS when it receives a message, so the same function is sending and receiving.

I've just received an email saying I've used over 85% of my free tier SQS requests quota, or over 850,000 requests in just the past 2 weeks. I'm certain these requests are not messages being sent to queue, or received. The number of sends/receives has to be under 1000 for how often I've used this app. I've also verified using SQS monitoring that there are no messages stuck in queue. And the number of sent messages is more or less what I expected, a low number.

Like I said this app is only being used by myself for testing, a few days per week. Where does the 850,000+ requests come from?

Comment: Please post the code of your lambda function. If the lambda is both sending and receiving, it almost sounds like you may have an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm certain that is not happening, the app is not sending messages when being triggered by SQS. I was thinking it could possibly be related to how lambda polls SQS when setup as an event source?

Comment: Well those messages are certainly coming from somewhere. Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to see the senders in CloudWatch, so you would have to figure out what resources have SendMessage permissions and then check those objects to see what they might be doing.

Comment: I'm fairly sure those 850,000 are not 'send' actions. Is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the original post. Per https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/ any API request counts against that quota, so yes, your thinking that it's related to the lambda polling the queue is probably on the right track. What does the number of empty receives look like?

Comment: @howcheng it's definitely empty receives. so it must be the polling. I think my confusion was how they led me to believe lambda was getting push notifications when receiving a message but in reality it's polling and those requests add up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon SQS is charged at $0.40 per million API calls. Calls include send, receive and delete, so it is possible that a message might use 3+ API calls.

From [AWS Lambda Adds Amazon Simple Queue Service to Supported Event Sources | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/):

> There are no additional charges for this feature, but because the Lambda service is continuously long-polling the SQS queue the account will be charged for those API calls at the standard SQS pricing rates.

Long-polling takes 20 seconds, which makes 4320 polls per day. This equates to 60,480 over two weeks or 129,600 per month. Admittedly, it would be more if messages are flowing, since long polling exits whenever there are messages.

So, either the queue is being used a lot (and you are getting excellent value for your $0.40) or you have something else generating lots of SQS API calls.

Comment: I actually had 2 other queues that I think were also set up as lambda triggers. So 3 queues were being polled. Plus add in the actual message flow, that must be where the 800k number came from.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same function for sending to SQS and receive from SQS, it means that:

Lambda send message to SQS -> SQS receive the message -> SQS trigger Lambda -> Lambda send message to SQS

And... It's an infinite loop :)